# I need to build a live demo of a user flow that takes user responses and keeps them anonymous

Tags: web, user-experience, web-testing, usability-testing

Hello smart people of stack overflow. My team need to create a live demo (**on the web preferably**) of our user flow and we want to be able to take user responses, have the responses be sent back to the user via email and for those responses to be anonymous so we can't see them.
Analytics are also important as well as we'd like to see how many users click all the way through to the end, if not, when they leave and just to measure general traffic and engagement.

If there's a platform, web builder or any software that allows us to do all (or at least most) of these things then that would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I have knowledge of wix and squarespace, I've also searched around for forms but they don't really accomplish what I need (unless I'm not looking hard enough).